# Two jenkins master common windows slave machine, will it cause any issues?

Tags: jenkins, build-automation, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I have two different jenkins. I have a windows machine which acts as a slave for both jenkins , workspace is different. I have used Launch Agent via java web start (slave.jar). I want to know that will this cause any problems. 
In short two different master have a common slave , will it cause any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will never cause an issue till the working directories of slaves are different. I had used this to be part of large CI setup with less than 8 machines with configurations of 20+ slaves

The same will be the case with different masters where the working directories of slaves are not the same on the remote machine